# Angular Update 14 to 15 - Styles broken

Tags: angular, angular15

we have an Angular 14 App that needs to be updated to 16, but somehow the stylesheets get messed up. It seems there are still the same scss files, but several attributes aren't present. In the Angular 14 Version it looks like this:

[image]

And after the update like this:

[image]

Do I have to fix all the broken parts manually or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Are these your styles, or styles that come from a library?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using Angular material. In Angular Material 15, styles have been updated to use mdc tokens.

You can read the details here;
https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

After updating to Angular 15, you can run following command to migrate your styles to mdc tokens.

> ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration

Answer (score 0):

Change css file to legacy in styles(angular.json)

F.e

from "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",

to "./node_modules/@angular/material/legacy-prebuilt-themes/legacy-pink-bluegrey.css",